# Loading template variables from another document

Tags: variables, modx, modx-evolution, modx-templates, modx-chunks

I have a document with `ID = 1`, which relies on a series of template variables in the format `[+template-variable-NUMBER+]`. I have filled fields using these values, and it's good for document `ID = 1`. What I want to do, however, is paste the values of the template variables for `ID = 1` into a document with `ID = 2`.

I want to use: `[+template-variable? id='1'+]` or something similar in `ID = 2`

In short, I need to have 3 groups of variables which are the same for both pages and I don't want to have to fill them in twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getField` snippet to achieve this: 
http://modx.com/extras/package/getfield

```
[!getField? &docid=`1` &field=`template-variable-name`!]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is the `fastField` extra http://modx.com/extras/package/fastfield

You can then access the template variables from another resource with the following notation.

> [[#1.tv.template-variable-NUMBER]]

Where the #1 is pointing to the resource ID=1, you can get most resource properties directly this way,it just the template variables which require the extra `.tv.` notation